# How to parallel multiple run with ncverilog?

Tags: linux, shell, verilog, cadence

I would like to run parallel multiple run ncverilog.

Normally,  we use ncverilog run script like this.

```
Run.scr-
ncveriog blar~blar~
```

But this is run at once. It means that if I want to run 100 scripts , I have to run new after previous script end. But I want to run at simultant 100 script.

How do I run the scripts at simultant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GNU Parallel`

```
parallel ncverilog bla bla
```

Normally, that will run as many `ncverilogs` in parallel as you have CPU cores, but you can add `-j 25`, for example, if you specifically want 25 to run in parallel.

If you need to supply lots of different parameters, just make a loop or script that generates the parameters and feeds a list of jobs into `GNU Parallel` like this:

```
for i in {0..99}; do
   echo ncverilog $i <and some other parameters>
done | parallel -j 25
```

[Example](http://davetang.org/muse/2013/11/18/using-gnu-parallel/)

[Example](https://www.biostars.org/p/63816/)

[Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html)

Comment: Is this woking just one cpu computer? or should I need like special i7 cpu which supported hyperthreading? My computer system has pentium 2 dual core cpu very old. So far I use old.

Comment: The first thing to do is check how many cores `GNU Parallel` thinks your computer has, so run this... `parallel --number-of-cores`

Comment: The second thing to do is check how much memory you have and how much memory your `ncverilog` program needs, so run these two... `awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo` and then run `/usr/bin/time -l ncverilog <args>`